# RecyclerView - listitem with unknown amount of elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listitem

i'm confronted with the following situation: i have a RecyclerView with 3 different viewtypes. Each contains a subtitle and then either a radio group, checkboxes or an editText. The problem is: the ammount of the elements (edittext,checkbox,radiobuttons) is variable so i am not able to create a static template as the viewtypes. So i'm trying to reach something like this (example with radiobuttons):

```
LISTVIEW
------------------
row1
      1) choice1
      2) choice2
------------------
row2
      1) choice1
      2) choice2
      3) choice3
------------------
row3
      1) choice1
-------------------
```

Any ideas about a good approach? Thanks for you time and help ! :)

EDIT: ChaitanyaAtkuris answer was quite helpful, but im getting a ClassCastException in the onBindViewHolder(). It says "cant cast TitleHolder to InputHolder" ... but i cant figure out why the holder object actually is a TitleHolder, because it uses the right case (INPUT) though. Here is my adapter code

```
public class RecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<Object> items;
private final int TITLE_VIEW = 0; 
private final int RADIO_GROUP = 1; 
private final int CHECK_BOX = 2; 
private final int INPUT = 3; 

public RecAdapter(List<Object> data) {
    this.items = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case CHECK_BOX:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_checkbox, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new CheckboxHolder(v1);
            break;
        case TITLE_VIEW:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_title, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v2);
            break;
        case INPUT:
            View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_inputfield, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v3);
            break;

    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ListItem item = (ListItem) items.get(position);
    if (item.getviewType()==TITLE_VIEW) {
        return TITLE_VIEW;
    } else if (item.getviewType()==RADIO_GROUP) {
        return RADIO_GROUP;
    } else if (item.getviewType()==CHECK_BOX) {
        return CHECK_BOX;
    } else if (item.getviewType()==INPUT) {
        return INPUT;
    }
        return -1;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case CHECK_BOX:
            CheckboxHolder checkboxHolder = (CheckboxHolder) holder;
            configureCheckBoxHolder(checkboxHolder, position);
            break;
        case TITLE_VIEW:
            TitleHolder titleHolder = (TitleHolder) holder;
            configureTitleHolder(titleHolder, position);
            break;
        case INPUT:
            InputHolder inputHolder = (InputHolder) holder;
            configureInputHolder(inputHolder, position);
            break;
    }
}

private void configureCheckBoxHolder(CheckboxHolder holder,int position)    {
    CheckBoxElement boxElement = (CheckBoxElement) items.get(position);
    if (boxElement != null) {
        holder.box.setText(boxElement.getText());
    }
}

private void configureInputHolder(InputHolder holder,int position)    {
    InputField field = (InputField) items.get(position);
    if (field != null) {
        holder.title.setText(field.getSubtitle());
    }
}

private void configureTitleHolder(TitleHolder holder,int position)    {
    TitlePojo titlePojo = (TitlePojo) items.get(position);
    if (titlePojo != null) {
        holder.titleText.setText(titlePojo.getTitle());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

private class InputHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title;
    private EditText inputfield;

    public InputHolder(View v1) {
        super(v1);
        title = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.inputTitleItem);
        inputfield = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.fieldItem);
    }
}

private class TitleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleText;

    public TitleHolder(View v1) {
        super(v1);
        titleText = (TextView)  v1.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    }
}

private class CheckboxHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CheckBox box;

    public CheckboxHolder(View v1) {
        super(v1);
        box = (CheckBox)   v1.findViewById(R.id.checkboxItem);
    }
}

private class RadioGroupHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RadioGroup group;

    public RadioGroupHolder(View v1) {
        super(v1);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are element1, element2, 3 here?

Comment: the rows in the recyclerView. I will change that

Comment: How about you create just one view with all the textviews, checkboxes and radio buttons you need and set their visibility to gone. You can change their visibility to visible in your holder if they are needed.

Comment: Create a common view with a textview for subtitle and a vertical linear layout. Then based on the values of view types add he textviews, checkboxes and radio buttons programmatically as and when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pynnie, This isn't a big deal. I believe you will resolve it. Lemme give you some light to resolve this.

Step1: As we have three different kinds of views as mentioned, lets take an `List<Object> dataList= new ArrayList();`This list will decide the total views to be displayed.

Step 2: Now, lets make a viewType for each of the component available. For example

```
private final int TEXT_VIEW = 0; //For TextView
private final int RADIO_GROUP = 1; //For RadioGroup
private final int CHECK_BOX = 2; //For individual Checkbox
private final int EDIT_TEXT = 3; //For Edit text individual
```

Now while storing the data dynamically basing upon the structure, store in the following way.

```
public class TextViewPojo { // This will used for identifying textViews

public String text;
//Any other necessary variables to hold data to display
}

public class EditTextPojo { // This will used for identifying editText

public String text;
//Any other necessary variables to hold data to display
}

public class RadioGroupPojo { // This will used for identifying RadioGroup

public int noOfRadioButtons;
//Any other necessary variables to hold data to display
}

public class CheckBoxPojo { // This will used for identifying checkbox

public String text;
//Any other necessary variables to hold data to display
}
```

// ------------------
    row1 - TextView indicating subTitle -> `dataList.add(new TextViewPojo());`
          1) choice1 - EditText - > `dataList.add(new EditTextPojo());`
          2) choice2- EditText - > `dataList.add(new EditTextPojo());`
    //------------------
    row2- TextView indicating subTitle -> `dataList.add(new TextViewPojo());`
          1) choice1 -CheckBox -> `dataList.add(new CheckBoxPojo());`
          2) choice2-CheckBox -> `dataList.add(new CheckBoxPojo());`
          3) choice3-CheckBox -> `dataList.add(new CheckBoxPojo());`
    //------------------
    row3 - TextView indicating subTitle -> `dataList.add(new TextViewPojo());`
          1) choice1 - RadioGroup For both choice1, choice2 consider as one as it a group of radio buttons, -> `RadioGroup -> dataList.add(new RadioGroupPojo());`
          2) choice2
    //-------------------

Now coming to the RecyclerView Adapter Implementation

public class RecyclerViewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
// The items to display in your RecyclerView
private List<Object> items; 
private final int TEXT_VIEW = 0; //For TextView
private final int RADIO_GROUP = 1; //For RadioGroup
private final int CHECK_BOX = 2; //For individual Checkbox
private final int EDIT_TEXT = 3; //For Edit text individual

public RecyclerViewsAdapter(List<Object> data,) {
this.items = data;
}
```

and now to differentiate the data, we shall use the getViewType() method

//Returns the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.

```
@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (items.get(position) instanceof CheckBoxPojo) {
          return CHECK_BOX;
      } else if (items.get(position) instanceof RadioGroupPojo) {
          return RADIOGROUP;
      } //All the conditions follow..
      return -1;
  }
```

Now create viewholders for each of the types.

```
public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView label1;

    public ViewHolder1(View v) {
        super(v);
        label1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }

    public TextView getLabel1() {
        return label1;
    }

    public void setLabel1(TextView label1) {
        this.label1 = label1;
    }
}
```

//All the other viewHolders accordingly.

```
@Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

      RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

      switch (viewType) {
          case CHECKBOX:
              View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder1, viewGroup, false);
              viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
              break;
          case RADIOGROUP:
              View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
              viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v2);
              break;
```

//And the rest cases follow.

NExt set data to views

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
      switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
          case CHECKBOX:
              ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
              configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
              break;
          case RADIOGROUp:
              ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
              configureViewHolder2(vh2, position);
              break;
//Rest cases follow.
          default:
              RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder) viewHolder;
              configureDefaultViewHolder(vh, position);
              break;
      }
  }

private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
      CheckBoxPojo user = (CheckBoxPojo) items.get(position);
      if (user != null) {
          vh1.getCheckBox1().setChecked(user.isChecked);
      }
  }

  private void configureViewHolder2(ViewHolder2 vh2) {
      //vh2.getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_golden_gate);
Similarly rest follows.
  }
```

And thats it done!!! You can configure in what ever way, how many ever it might be, how random they might be even.

REFERENCE : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

**EDIT :**

To find out the issue in the snippet added by you. Below is the issue :

`case TITLE_VIEW: View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_title, parent, false); viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v2); break; case INPUT: View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_inputfield, parent, false); viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v3); break;`

In both these cases you are using title holder only.

Comment: thanks for the help, this seems to be the right approach! Very nice explanation! But I still have an issue in 'onBindViewholder()'. Its really weired because the first item (TitlePojo) is no problem but the next item is an editTextPojo throws a classCastException. It jumps to the right case, where it should be cast to a ViewHolder für EditText but somehow the passed ViewHolder is still a TitleHolder which cant be cast into an EditTextHolder... I dont get whats wrong

Comment: @Pynnie, paste the snippet of code where you are facing this issue and exact issue u r getting

Comment: I believe the issue might be with getItemViewType method. Please verify it once again while preparing the objects. If still exists paste your entire adapter class

Comment: i already checked it and coudln't find a mistake. But i edited my whole adapter into the question. maybe you can see more than me

Comment: Here lies the issue.

Comment: case TITLE_VIEW: View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_title, parent, false); viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v2); break; case INPUT: View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_inputfield, parent, false); viewHolder = new TitleHolder(v3); break; both these cases u r using title holder only